# Error while logging through ssh on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, ssh, raspberrypi

I was trying to access my raspberry pi 4 from my ubuntu machine through ssh and when i rite the following command in my terminal `ssh @ipaddress` I am getting this following error. I am not sure how to solve this up as i am new to it.

```
usage: ssh [some characters shown here] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]
```

Can someone please help me out in this? I would really appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: That's not an error. It's help. It shows when you make mistakes in your ssh command. It's offering you suggestions on how to write the command correctly.

Comment: The `destination` should either be in the form `user@ipaddress` / `user@hostname` or just `ipaddress` / `hostname` . In the latter two cases, the `user` will be taken from your local login name, unless you have a `.ssh/config` file that specifies otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you missed the username. On a Raspberry Pi, the username is usually "pi" so if you want to run the `ls` command on the Rpi from your Ubuntu computer, the command should look like `ssh pi@ipaddress ls` and it should prompt you for the pi password. ssh will run the ls on Rpi, send the output back to Ubuntu, and then finish by handing control back to the Ubuntu session.

The "pi@ipaddress" section corresponds to the "destination" placeholder in the usage guidelines you mistook for an error. The complete documentation can be seen by running `man ssh` but that can be overwhelming to a beginner.